# Python. Find value in a complex dictionary by key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a complicated dictionary from which I need to get the account number and balance.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url=HOST_GET + str("8af*********************e66b024e"), headers=headers, data=payload)
data = response.json()
```

response

```
{
"reportKey": "8af*********************e66b024e",
"status": "COMPLETE",
"items": [
    {
        "glAccount": {
            "encodedKey": "8af6a********b66017*********00e",
            "glCode": "1235802509PLN",
            "type": "ASSET",
            "usage": "DETAIL",
            "name": "Some account 2",
            "stripTrailingZeros": false,
            "currency": {
                "code": "USD"
            }
        },
        "amounts": {
            "openingBalance": 18.1200000000
        }
    },
    {
        "glAccount": {
            "encodedKey": "8a**********10018************2e2",
            "glCode": "12188009912PKOUSD01",
            "type": "ASSET",
            "usage": "DETAIL",
            "name": "UAH account(payment channel acct.)",
            "stripTrailingZeros": false,
            "currency": {
                "code": "USD"
            }
        },
        "amounts": {
            "openingBalance": 155532.5900000000
        }
    },
    {
        "glAccount": {
            "encodedKey": "8af*********0719d0179***********f",
            "glCode": "1134800294USD",
            "type": "ASSET",
            "usage": "DETAIL",
            "name": "UAH account",
            "stripTrailingZeros": false,
            "currency": {
                "code": "USD"
            }
        },
        "amounts": {
            "openingBalance": 455219.9500000000
        }
    },
    {
        "glAccount": {
            "encodedKey": "8*************5fed***************1a4",
            "glCode": "124567376001EUR",
            "type": "ASSET",
            "usage": "DETAIL",
            "name": "EUR account",
            "stripTrailingZeros": false,
            "currency": {
                "code": "EUR"
            }
        },
        "amounts": {
            "openingBalance": 14.0000000
        }
    }
        ]
}
```

I hard-coded the search, but the code must be redone constantly when new accounts appear.

```
if data["items"][2]["glAccount"]["glCode"] == "1134800294USD":
glaccount =  data["items"][2]["glAccount"]["glCode"]
amount1 = data["items"][2]["amounts"]["openingBalance"]
print('Account -', data["items"][2]["glAccount"]["glCode"], "Amount -", data["items"][2]["amounts"]["openingBalance"])
```

response

```
Account - 1134800294USD Amount - 455219.95
```

I need to find the right account and then get the amount in the account. I have little experience in this, so please help.

Comment: use a for loop to iterate through `items`  then you can check for the account inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try below for loop to get the values, instead of print you can save them as variable or create new dictionary.

```
for item in json["items"]:
    print(f'Account ID: {item["glAccount"]["glCode"]}')
    print(f'Account Balance: {item["amounts"]["openingBalance"]}')
```

Example;

```
accounts={}

for item in json["items"]:
    account_id = ({item["glAccount"]["glCode"]})
    account_balance = ({item["amounts"]["openingBalance"]})
    accounts_to_be_added = {f'{account_id}': account_balance}
    accounts.update(accounts_to_be_added)
```